# How to integrate $\int \frac{1}{\cos(x)}\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

could you help me on this integral ?

$$\int \frac{1}{\cos(x)}\,\mathrm dx$$

Here's what I've started :

$$\int \frac{1}{\cos(x)}\,\mathrm dx = \int \frac{\cos(x)}{\cos(x)^2}\,\mathrm dx = \int \frac{\cos(x)}{1-\sin(x)^2}\,\mathrm dx$$

Now, I did : $u = \sin(x)$, so $\mathrm du = 1$.

Now I have :

$$\int \frac{\text{???}}{1-u^2}\,\mathrm du$$

But at this point, I think I did the most of the job but I'm stuck. Could you help me to solve this integral please (to the integration by substitution at the end) ?

Thanks

**EDIT :**

Now I follow the steps and I got :

$$\int \frac{1}{1-u^2}\,\mathrm du$$
Doing the partial fraction I got $A = 1/2$ and $B = 1/2$.

So basically I have :

\begin{align}
& \int \frac{1}{1-u^2}\,\mathrm du = \int \frac{1/2}{1+u}\,\mathrm du + \int \frac{1/2}{1-u}\,\mathrm du \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac 1 2 \left(\int \frac{1}{1+u} \, du - \int \frac{1}{1-u} \, du\right) \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac 1 2 \ln\left(\frac{1+u}{1-u}\right) = \ln\left(\left(\frac{1+\sin(x)}{1-\sin(x)}\right)^{1/2}\right) \\[8pt]
= {} & \ln \left(\frac{\sqrt{1+\sin(x)}}{\sqrt{1-\sin(x)}}\right) = \ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+\sin(x)}}{\sqrt{\cos(x)^2}}\right) \\[8pt]
= {} & \ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+\sin(x)}}{\cos(x)}\right)
\end{align}

Here's what my teacher got :

[image]

What's wrong with what I did ? Did I miss something ?

Comment: $du=\cos x\,dx$, which brings you to $\int\frac{du}{1-u^2}$. Now use partial fractions.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks for the hint. Could you see my edit please ?

Comment: @user2336315 Note that since:
$$\sec x + \tan x = \dfrac{1}{\cos x} + \dfrac{\sin x}{\cos x} = \dfrac{1+\sin x}{\cos x}$$
this is equivalent to my answer. Looking at your work, you should have done:
$$
\sqrt{\dfrac{1+\sin x}{1 - \sin x}} = \sqrt{\dfrac{1+\sin x}{1 - \sin x} \cdot \dfrac{1+\sin x}{1 + \sin x}} = \sqrt{\dfrac{(1+\sin x)^2}{1 - \sin^2 x}} = 
\sqrt{\dfrac{(1+\sin x)^2}{\cos^2 x}} = 
\dfrac{1+\sin x}{\cos x} 
$$

Comment: @Adriano Nice !

Comment: Towards the end, when you "multiplied top and bottom by $1+\sin x$" you forgot to multiply the top. By the way, the conventional way of putting it is $\ln(|\sec x+\tan x|)$ and there is a quick excessively magic way to do it all in one line.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Alternatively, observe that:
$$
\int \dfrac{1}{\cos x} dx = \int \sec x~dx = \int \sec x \left(\dfrac{\sec x + \tan x}{\sec x + \tan x}\right) dx = \int\dfrac{\sec^2 x + \sec x \tan x}{\sec x + \tan x} dx
$$
Now let $u=\sec x + \tan x$ so that $du = (\sec x \tan x + \sec^2x)~dx$. Then we obtain:
$$
\int\dfrac{(\sec x \tan x + \sec^2 x)~dx}{\sec x + \tan x} = \int \dfrac{du}{u}=\ln|u|+C= \boxed{\ln|\sec x + \tan x|+C}
$$

Comment: whilst this is a well-known method, it is difficult to do if you do not know it

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align}
& \int\frac{1}{1-u^2}\,du=\frac12\int\left(\frac{1}{1+u}+\frac{1}{1-u}\right) \,du \\[8pt]
=  {} & \frac12(\ln(1+u)-\ln(1-u))+\color{red }{\ln c} = \ln\left(\color{red }{c}\sqrt{\frac{1+u}{1-u}} \, \right)
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks ! Upvoted ! Could you see my edit please ?

Comment: I don't get you. What do you mean by add its constant ?

Answer (score 1):

You can also remember that :$1/\cos(x)=\sec(x)$

Comment: What good will that do? ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but I spotted the mistake in your solution after the edit.

You wrote 1-sin(x) = cos(x)^2 (which is wrong for obvious reasons)

Comment: This would probably be better as a comment (I think).

Comment: I didn't downvote by the way.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{\sqrt{1+\sin(x)}}{\sqrt{1-\sin(x)}} = \frac{\sqrt{1+\sin(x)}\sqrt{1+\sin(x)}}{\sqrt{1-\sin(x)}\sqrt{1+\sin(x)}} = \frac{1+\sin(x)}{\sqrt{\cos(x)^2}} =\text{etc.}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is another try:
$$I=\int\sec(x)dx=\int\frac{1}{\cos(x)}dx$$
now $u=\cos(x)$ so $dx=\frac{du}{-\sin(x)}$ then:
$$I=-\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}u}du$$
then we can use $v=1-u^2$ so $du=\frac{dv}{-2u}$ and the integral becomes:
$$I=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{v(1-v)}dv$$
and by using partial fraction decomposition we can obtain:
$$\frac{1}{v(1-v)}=\frac{1}{v}+\frac{1}{1-v}$$
and so our integral becomes:
$$I=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{v}+\frac{1}{1-v}dv=\frac{1}{2}\ln|\frac{v}{1-v}|+C=\frac{1}{2}\ln|\frac{1-u^2}{u^2}|+C=\frac{1}{2}\ln|\frac{1-\cos^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}|+C$$
although this looks wrong to me

Answer (score 0):

Notice how$$\left[\sec x\right]’_x=\sec x\tan x$$$$\left[\tan x\right]’_x=\sec^2 x$$A factor of $\sec x$ shows up in both results of the derivative! Adding the two equations together gives$$\left[\sec x\right]’_x+\left[\tan x\right]’_x=\sec x(\tan x+\sec x)$$Divide both sides by $\sec x+\tan x$ and integrate with respect to $x$. The right-hand side becomes the integral you’re looking$$\begin{align*}\int\mathrm dx\,\sec x & =\int\mathrm dx\,\frac {\left[\sec x\right]’_x+\left[\tan x\right]’_x}{\tan x+\sec x}\\ & =\int\frac {\mathrm du}u\\ & =\log(\sec x+\tan x)+C\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \sec d x &=\int \frac{\cos x}{\cos ^{2} x} d x \\
&=\int \frac{1}{(1+\sin x)(1-\sin x)} d(\sin x) \\
&=\frac{1}{2} \int \left(\frac{1}{1-\sin x}+\frac{1}{1+\sin x}\right) d (\sin x) \\
&=\frac{1}{2} \ln \left|\frac{1+\sin x}{1-\sin x} \right| +C \\
&=\frac{1}{2} \ln \left|\frac{(1+\sin x)^{2}}{\cos ^{2} x}\right| +C\\
&=\ln \left|\frac{1+\sin x}{\cos x}\right| +C\\&=\ln |\sec x+\tan x|+C
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{\cos{x}}=\frac{\cos{x}}{\cos^{2}{x}}=\frac{\cos{x}}{1-\sin^{2}{x}}$

$\displaystyle \sin{x}=u\Rightarrow du=\cos{x} dx$

$\displaystyle \frac{dx}{\cos{x}}=\frac{\ du}{1-\ u^{2}}=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{u-1}-\frac{1}{u+1})$

$\displaystyle \int\frac{dx}{\cos{x}}=\ln\sqrt{ \frac{{\sin{x}-1}}{{\sin{x}+1}}}+c$

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the standard approach (Euler formula) when integrating trigonometric functions can be used, but it will take a different form, i.e.,
\begin{align}
\int{\frac{1}{\cos x}dx}&=\int\frac{2e^{ix}}{e^{2ix}+1}dx\\
&=-2i\tan^{-1}(e^{ix})+C\\
&=\ln\left|\frac{1-ie^{ix}}{1+ie^{ix}}\right|+C
\end{align}

which is equivalent to $\ln\sqrt{\left|\frac{\sin x+1}{\sin x-1}\right|}+C$ since
\begin{align}
\sqrt{\left|\frac{\sin x+1}{\sin x-1}\right|}=
\sqrt{\left|\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}+2i}{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}-2i}\right|}=
\sqrt{\left|\frac{e^{2ix}-1+2ie^{ix}}{e^{2ix}-1-2ie^{ix}}\right|}=
\sqrt{\left(\frac{e^{ix}+i}{e^{ix}-i}\right)^2}=\left|\frac{1-ie^{ix}}{1+ie^{ix}}\right|
\end{align}