# Evaluate the definite integral $\int_{0}^{a} \frac{x\cdot dx}{x+\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_{0}^{a} \frac{x \cdot dx}{x+\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}$$
This is what I tried:

Let $x=a\cdot \sin(t)$

$$\int_{0}^{a} \frac{x\cdot dx}{x+\sqrt{a^2-x^2}} = \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{a\sin(t)\cdot a\cos(t)dt}{a\sin(t)+a\cos(t)} = a\cdot\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin(t)\cdot \cos(t)dt}{\sin(t)+\cos(t)}$$

I can't this of a way to integrate this

Comment: you can try $\sin t \cos t=\frac{(\sin t +\cos t)^2-1}{2}$.

Comment: There are many ways to solve this integral. Personally, I would not go with trigonometric substitution. Rationalize the fraction to get rid of the root in the denominator. Then, use linearity. If you do want to stick with a trigonometric substitution, you might want to give [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. We have that
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin(t)\cdot \cos(t)}{\sin(t)+\cos(t)}dt=
\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{(\sin(t)+\cos(t))^2}{\sin(t)+\cos(t)}
-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dt}{\sin(t)+\cos(t)}.$$
For the last integral, note that $\sin(t)+\cos(t)=\sqrt{2}\cos(t-\pi/4)$ and
see [How to integrate $\int \frac{1}{\cos(x)}\,\mathrm dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419140/how-to-integrate-int-frac1-cosx-mathrm-dx)